# My dollar signs are now little boxes

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport, jasperserver

This week we upgraded to JasperReports Server 4.7 (Professional) and iReport 4.7. I have several reports that I created in iReport 4.5.1 and successfully used in JasperReports Server 4.5.1.

After the upgrade, all of my dollar signs are now little boxes. The pattern for my currency fields is ¤ #,##0.00. JasperReports Server is not replacing the box with a dollar sign when the report is generated. Everything looks ok in the pattern sample. My percentage symbols are all still working. I tried removing and applying the currency pattern to the fields again, but this didn't fix the problem.

Any thoughts on how I can fix this?

Comment: have you tried changing the character codification? (First line of the report: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>)

Comment: Thank you! I double checked, and all of my XML files and Tomcat are set to UTF-8 encoding. I have a feeling that I need to edit something in a locale file to indicate that I should be getting dollar signs. If I change my locale from English to Spanish or French I am still getting the same placeholder boxes instead of a currency symbol. This only happens on the JasperReports Server side, not in iReport.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is Java operating as intended... but not as you *want* it to operate. Your locale does not specify a currency, so you get that "¤" symbol.

You could workaround it by changing your locale from "en" to "en_US". I just did this last week. As a side note, I found one tweak that I needed to make. After changing the locale to en_US I needed to copy one file like this:

```
cp .../jasperserver-pro/scripts/jquery/js/jquery.ui.datepicker-en.js .../jasperserver-pro/scripts/jquery/js/jquery.ui.datepicker-en-US.js
```

Alternatively, I usually find it's better to work around it by setting your format mask to use a hard-coded dollar sign. If you are displaying "$50.00" to a user in the United States, it would be nonsensical to display "€50,00" to a European user or "¥50.00" to a Japanese user for the same value. There are lots of times when the hard-coded currency symbol is more appropriate.

Comment: Thank you, Matthew! All of my currency values are US dollars so this gives me something to consider. Perhaps those dollar signs should be hard-coded. I'll also change our locale -- thank you for the instructions for copying that file.